# How to make a ToolbarItem centered while keeping others trailing and leading in SwiftUI for macOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Build for macOS. I want to make a toolbar like Safari's toolbar, that there are three parts (leading, centered, and trailing). And the centered part stays at the absolutely center, no matter how long leading or trailing part is or changes to.
[image]

My code would be like below, but failed to achieve my requirement. As shown in the screenshot below, the trailing placements (`.confirmationAction`, `.primaryAction`, `.automatic` etc.) all don't work. If a `ToolbarItem` whose placement is `.principal` exists, the trailing part attach to it closely. Also, I find the `.principal` is not absolutely centered. The position is depending on the leading part.

How can I solve this and meet the requirement? Or some alternative methods rather than `.toolbar{}`?

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        Button {} label: {
            Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                .scaleEffect(1.5)
        }
    }
            
    ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
        Button {} label: {
            Image(systemName: "star")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using Spacer() is the best option here because it will separate space between your item fairly. Put your images/components between Spacer().You can use this method with other Stack/Container too, not just HStack. NOTE: this is an alternative way relates to poster's request. Try code below the image:

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct UsingSpacer__: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            
            Image(systemName: "square.fill")
            
            Spacer()
            
            Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
            
            Spacer()
            
            Image(systemName: "cloud.fill")
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(.blue)
    }
   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```swift
.toolbar {
    // centered image
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            SomeImage
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
        }
    }

    // item on the right
    ToolbarItem(placement: .destructiveAction) { ... }
}
```

This trick sets the size of the ToolbarItem on the image and then overflows the image off the container if it is too big. But unless you add `.clipped()` it won’t clip and it will look right.

The problem is that ToolbarItem seems to follow some internal algorithm that balances the size of the ToolbarItem with the size of the left/right button, and the margin to the edges of the screen. This may result in the principal item not being centered.

Another option would be setting a fixed size for the image:

```
SomeImage
    .resizable()
    .frame(width: 130, height: 30)
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
```

Or to balance the size of the item in the right with an item on the left (or a Spacer) of the same size. This would center the ToolbarItem in the middle.